# How can I use FCM from within Firebase function

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a FCM from within a firebase function but I'm getting the following error every time:

```
await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationToken, message)
```

I followed the suggestions from [this post, of the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770005/how-can-i-use-firebase-functions-to-send-fcm-to-user), no help.  Pointing to [Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), another link in the article, isn't very helpful as I am using Firebase Server.

This article, same, [Sending FCM using Firebase Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59676856/sending-fcm-using-firebase-functions) and I'm using the same code (the FCM code), same error.

This is the full error:

```
Error sending message: { Error: An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions. Raw server response: "<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
". Status code: 401.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:43:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:89:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:255:16)
    at Object.createFirebaseError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-errors-internal.js:57:12)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request-internal.js:78:51
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  errorInfo:
   { code: 'messaging/authentication-error',
     message:
      'An error occurred when trying to authenticate to the FCM servers. Make sure the credential used to authenticate this SDK has the proper permissions. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup for setup instructions. Raw server response: "<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Unauthorized</H1>\n<H2>Error 401</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n". Status code: 401.' },
  codePrefix: 'messaging' }
```

Answer (score 5):

How I solved it:

1. Go to [Google Service Account](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts) and select your project.
2. It will display a list of accounts. Click on the account *something*@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
3. Select tab "Keys". Generate a new key and download it as a JSON.
4. Lastly, add the generated JSON to your projects using the function *.cert()*:

***This is only for testing, remember to remove the credentials when you deploy your functions!***

```html
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(
    "route/to/generatedJSON.json"
  ),
});
const messaging = admin.messaging();
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, unrelated but related I found the answer...

[gcp-the-caller-does-not-have-a-permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63876853/gcp-the-caller-does-not-have-a-permission)

Basically, follow [these](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/quickstart) instructions to add

> Firebase Admin

to your .gserviceaccount.com account.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me try it:
1- Go to google cloud.
2- then go to API and Services.
3- then Enabled API and Services.
4- then turn on the cloud messaging and Turn on Firebase cloud messaging API.

Comment: Could you provide a more detailed answer? Also, it would be great if you format your answer correctly! [Take a look at this article!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)